# Why the text in the ui texts values are all the same 9,9?

Tags: unity, c#

At the top :

```
public List<Text> texts = new List<Text>();
```

Than when creating a grid :

```
IEnumerator CreateGrid()
{
    gridBlocks = new Transform[gridWidth, gridHeight];

    for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnSpeed);

        for (int z = 0; z < gridHeight; z++)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnSpeed);

            GameObject block = Instantiate(gridPrefab, Vector3.zero, gridPrefab.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
            block.transform.parent = transform;
            block.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x + x * gap, 0, z + z * gap);
            block.tag = "Grid Block";
            texts.Add(block.GetComponentInChildren<Text>());
            gridBlocks[x, z] = block.transform;
            gridBlocksPositions.Add(block.transform.position);
            if ((x == 0) || (x == gridWidth - 1) || (z == 0) || (z == gridHeight - 1))
            {
                gridOuterBlocks.Add(block.transform.position);

                var cubeRenderer = block.GetComponent<Renderer>();
                cubeRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
            }
        }
    }

    if (Random.Range(0, 2) == 0)
    {
        var blockRenderer = gridBlocks[0, Random.Range(0, gridHeight)].GetComponent<Renderer>();
        blockRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.blue);
        startBlockPOs = blockRenderer.transform.position;
        blockRenderer = gridBlocks[gridWidth - 1, Random.Range(0, gridHeight)].GetComponent<Renderer>();
        blockRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.blue);
        endBlockPos = blockRenderer.transform.position;
    }
    else
    {
        var blockRenderer = gridBlocks[Random.Range(0, gridWidth), 0].GetComponent<Renderer>();
        blockRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.blue);
        startBlockPOs = blockRenderer.transform.position;
        blockRenderer = gridBlocks[Random.Range(0, gridWidth), gridHeight - 1].GetComponent<Renderer>();
        blockRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.blue);
        endBlockPos = blockRenderer.transform.position;
    }
    gridGenerated = true;

    Test();
}
```

Inside the CreateGrid method I'm getting the text from each block :

```
texts.Add(block.GetComponentInChildren<Text>());
```

Than inside Test I loop over the texts and writing to each text the x and y of each block.
It should show me the text 0,0 than 0,1 then 0,2 and so on...
Instead it's showing on all the texts 9,9

The grid in this case height and width are 10.

```
private void Test()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < texts.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < gridHeight; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < gridWidth; y++)
            {
                blocksX.Add(x.ToString());
                blocksY.Add(y.ToString());

                texts[i].text = x.ToString() + ", " + y.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
private void Test()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < gridHeight; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < gridWidth; y++)
        {
            blocksX.Add(x.ToString());
            blocksY.Add(y.ToString());

            int index = y + x * gridWidth;
            texts[index].text = x.ToString() + ", " + y.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

In your code, all steps of your inner 2 loops run for all steps of your outermost loop. Therefore you are running the innermost loop body 100 (10 * 10) times for all your texts. Only the last steps of your inner loops persist before the outermost loop moves forward, leaving all your texts at (9, 9).